# Android - cache installation problem

Tags: android, apk

I am wondering if it's possible to delete file, which has been downloaded by URL connetion as a autoupdate right after installation? This *.apk should not be available for public, so I am deleting it from SD card when the app starts for the next time, but is there any other (better) way of dealing with it right after installation?

Thanks

edit: instalation of APK

```
    menu.mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    Intent install=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    install.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(ctx.getCacheDir()+"/app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    ctx.startActivity(install);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try saving it at `context.getCacheDir()`. It's not visible to other apps (or non-root users).

Be sure to delete it as soon as possible (next time user starts your app, or listen for PACKAGE_INSTALLED broadcast) to avoid filling up your user's phone's internal memory!

Good luck
Tom

Comment: Thanks, but when the app starts and I haven't downloaded any file to getCacheDir, it will crash

Comment: Then you should simpley check at startup if the file is available or not. If it is - delete it. If not - start the app...

`File.exists()` is probably what you're looking for. ;)

Comment: So i have implemented it and I am getting error, when installing apk downloaded to getCacheDir(). It sais unable to read Android Manifest, failed to parse manifest, unable to open apk, permission denied... does is need some special permission?

Comment: if so, what permission? I have tried two concerning cache but no success

Comment: You don't need any permissions for getCacheDir(). How do you install the downloaded apk?

Comment: Damn, looks like cache isn't the right place for your apk, sorry. :/

I fear you have to download it to SDCard...